# How can I write after wrapfigure without wrapping the Text?

Tags: formatting, wrapfigure, text

I'm trying to type some things from school in LaTeX. I encountered a problem:
If I use the wrapfigure command, with a very short text, the next paragraph also wrap, which I don't want.
Here is the code:

```
            \subsubsection{Des E-Feld eines Plattenkondensators}

        \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{B2}
                \caption{Das E-Feld eines Plattenkondensators.}
                \caption*{Quelle: Selbst erstellt}
                \label{fig: Das E-Feld eines Plattenkondensators}
        \end{wrapfigure} Im inneren des Plattenkondensators spricht man von einem \textcolor{green}{homogenem Feld}.


        \subsection{Die elektrische Feldstärke E}
            Für das \textcolor{green}{Kräftedreieck} gilt:\\
            $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\vec{F_el}}{\vec{F_G}} \Leftrightarrow \vec{F_el}=\tan(\alpha)\cdot \vec{F_G}$

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please minimize your code example (only relevant paragraphs and using an example image (like `example-image.pdf`) instead of an image we do not have?

Comment: Aside: You should use `\[formula\]` instead of `{\centering $formula$}`.

Comment: also never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph like `\end{tabular}\\` (latex presumably warns you about that).  `wrapfig` has an optional argument to say how many lines to wrap. (we can not run your example to demonstrate, you could edit using `example-image`  which is generally available

Comment: For pretty printing numbers and units you should maybe take a look at [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). You could then use something like `\SI{1}{\ampere} entspricht ungefähr \SI{6.24e18}{\electron\per\second}` with `\DeclareSIUnit\electron{e^-}` in your preamble.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for the tip with `\[formular\]`.
I don't know what you mean by using `(example-image.pdf)`.  

@DavidCarlisle I tried `\begin{wrapfigure}[2]{l}{0.4\textwidth}` but he just throws the next Paragraph in my picture... I don't know why...

Comment: Use `example-image.pdf` as file name for includegraphics and try to reproduce the unwanted behavior.

Comment: Hi @TeXnician I've added the `example-image.pdf` and updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `tabularx` in the place of `wrapfigure`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig, tabularx, caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{2}


\begin{document}


          \subsubsection{Des E-Feld eines Plattenkondensators}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{0.4\linewidth}X@{}}
           \color{green} {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, valign=t]{B2}}\newline
            \captionof{figure}{Das E-Feld eines Plattenkondensators.}
            \caption*{Quelle: Selbst erstellt}
            \label{fig: Das E-Feld eines Plattenkondensators}
 & Im inneren des Plattenkondensators spricht man von einem \textcolor{green}{homogenem Feld}.
    \end{tabularx}


    \subsection{Die elektrische Feldstärke E}
        Für das \textcolor{green}{Kräftedreieck} gilt:\\
        $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\vec{F_el}}{\vec{F_G}} \Leftrightarrow \vec{F_el}=\tan(\alpha)\cdot \vec{F_G}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Bernard. This helped quite a lot. I got it to work. Thanks a lot.